# Out of memory matlab

Tags: matlab, memory

I'm trying to solve a large linear programming task and have large matrixes.
After

```
[x,fval,exitflag] = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,[],[]);
```

Matlab says:

```
Error using builtin
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.  
Error in lipsol (line 720)
Rinf = builtin('_cholinf',sparse(P(perm,perm)));
Error in linprog (line 272)
[x,fval,lambda,exitflag,output]
=lipsol(f,A,B,Aeq,Beq,lb,ub,options,defaultopt,computeLambda);
```

Answer to memory command:

```
Maximum possible array:     87 MB (9.088e+07 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:    877 MB (9.197e+08 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:    650 MB (6.817e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   3057 MB (3.206e+09 bytes)
```

So what shall I do to increase my memory?
Win 7 x86, 4 Gb RAM

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MATLAB page on increasing the memory used for a process: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html. This is what they say specifically about Windows systems: "Use the Windows Control Panel to change the size of the virtual memory paging file on your system. For more information, refer to the Windows help."